# Cant run simple node.js app throwing Error: listen EACCES

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I ussually code on c9 I am trying to get work on my local environment, Im a trying a ver silly app but I get an error.

APP:

```
//APP IMPORTS
var express    = require('express'),
    app        = express()


//INDEX PAGE
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Welcome');
});


app.listen('localhost', 30000, function() {
   console.log("mirror server started!"); 
});
```

Error:

```
λ node app.js
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES localhost
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1269:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1334:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1432:5)
    at Function.listen (c:\Moi\mirror\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Moi\mirror\app.js:12:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1313:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Not sure why this is happening I was trying first with process.env.IP and process.env.PORT but I didnt want to set the environment vars yet, and I dont know what ip node uses for default, so I tried like thisnot sure why it doesnt work, I also tried with an ip like '127.0.0.22' and PORT 3000, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the port number and "bind host" in the wrong order. It should be:

```
app.listen(30000, 'localhost', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following to get your app started:

```
//APP IMPORTS
var express    = require('express'),
    app        = express()


//INDEX PAGE
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Welcome');
});

app.set('port', 30000);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log("mirror server started!"); 
});
```

Your server should automaticaly get `localhost` as host and change as soon as you work on production with your server host.

**Another way**

Just replace the order of your listen function parameter like:

```
app.listen(30000, 'localhost',  function() {
   console.log("mirror server started!"); 
});
```

The signature like express described looks like this: `app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])`

Source: [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html)
You can find [here](https://gist.github.com/indiesquidge/7fe1d8be1b973f782c97) a small explanation on how express handelt `server config`